# Java desktop application excel upload with Apache POI

Tags: java, nlp, apache-poi

I need to create a Java desktop application which will allow users to upload an excel file. The file then will be read and written by apache poi codes. Then the modified file should be downloadable by the user.

The code I found online below reads a file from a specific location, I would like it to read it directly once it is uploaded by the user.

```
public class ReadWriteExcelFile {

    public static void readXLSFile() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("C:/Test.xls");
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);

        HSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFRow row; 
        HSSFCell cell;

        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();

        while (rows.hasNext())
        {
            row=(HSSFRow) rows.next();
            Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

            while (cells.hasNext())
            {
                cell=(HSSFCell) cells.next();

                if (cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                {
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+" ");
                }
                else if(cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
                {
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue()+" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    //U Can Handel Boolean, Formula, Errors
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

How can I also get the Apache POI read to just read items in one column and save each cell value in a variable?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Upload to what?  A web service listening on HTTP?

Comment: I am really open to suggestions on that (I am a beginner)

Comment: If it's a desktop application, then why does the user need to upload anything to it? Why can't they just use a file picker dialogue to select the file directly?

Comment: Oh okay I can go with that. in this case the the file picker will dynamically show the file location ? Does Apache poi then updates the file that's already on ones device ? Because in this case the user won't have to download the modified file either